# Angular 4 Shared Service Observable Behavior Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an BehaviorSubject as part of a SharedServices Module that is provided to the AppModule in the Providers section of the module and subscribe to it in the AppComponent. I also subscribe to it in another component that is part of another Module AdminModule but I'm not getting the changes unless I add it to it Providers section of the AppComponent. Why is this? I thought if you add it to the Providers section in the Module and subscribe all subscribers would get the changes?

I have to do this for the child components to get the changes. I'm really confused by this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers : [ AppsSharedService]    <--------
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I'd expect - if you declare it in the component-level providers you'll have *more* instances, not fewer. Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to follow the guidance of the Angular docs and move this global provider out of that "shared" module and into a "core" module:

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#no-shared-module-providers

I suspect what's happening here is the service is created twice, so changes that are happening in one aren't reflected in all.

Comment: yeah but I have the AppModule and and AdminModule that's why I have a SharedService module so the AppModule and AdminModule can both reference it. If i add only to the AppModule I won't be able to reference in the AdminModule but my question is on BehaviorSubject Subscription.

So if you subscribe to BehaviorSubject it doesn't Publish to all the Subscribers, you have to have one instance and declare in the AppComponent for a singleton??

The AdminModule is lazy loaded as well. I'm really confused.

Comment: Read that documentation I linked to, in particular this section: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#why-bother. There's a big difference in where you use a provider (the service that has your BehaviorSubject) and how it's *provided*. You are free to import the service itself into components, but it must only be provided once to get the behavior you are asking for.

Comment: As suggested in the original comment on the question, it could help to build that simple example of your code that demonstrates the failure you mention. From that it should be easy to identify the fix...you might even figure it out just by trying to make a simple example.

Comment: Oh, so that's just for singleton service, I should only provide once in app module and no where else but can still reference. I read the docs, still was a little confusing but I think I got it. It works now with being provided in the AppModule without in AppComponent as well. 

Thanks you very much!

Comment: I guess I will make a coremodule for all the singleton services so I know to only provide once in the AppModule. I get it now. This is first time I ran across this issue.