# Sharing data between 2 components of 2 different modules Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In my application there are 2 modules i.e **AppModule** and **UserModule**.

But I am facing a problem in sharing data between the **AppComponent** and **LoginComponent(which is a part of UserModule).**

Here is app.component.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav lg-nav visible-lg visible-md">
        <li><a routerLinkActive="nav-active" routerLink="/page1">page1</a></li>
        <li><a routerLinkActive="nav-active" *ngIf="!loggedIn" routerLink="/user/login">Login</a></li>

</ul>
```

app.component.ts

```
    import { MessageService } from './services/message.service';
   export class AppComponent {
    loggedIn = false;
    constructor(private ms: MessageService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      this.ms.getMessage().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('messageService: ', data);
      if (data === 'login') {
        this.loggedIn = !this.loggedIn;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

login.component.ts (UserModule)

```
    constructor(
     private ms: MessageService
    ) {}
    -> call to login service
    -> on success response
    this.ms.sendMessage('login');
```

message.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  private message = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() {}
  sendMessage(message) {
    this.message.next({ message: message });
  }
  clearMessage() {
    this.message.next();
  }
  getMessage() {
    return this.message.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The problem is that the observer is not being subscribed in **app.component.ts**
I tried using MessageService in a shared module but all in vein.
What can I do to send the message to AppComponent from LoginComponent(UserModule) when user logs in so that the Login Button may gets disappear.

Comment: If you define the service in two modules, each will get a separate instance of it.

Comment: Move your loggedin logic into the Login service itself,  so when you call the service you can check the same variable from any component / module.  as it stands now you have your login variable in your app component.   store that in the service and setup a function to check if you are logged in,  a function to log out, and a function to login and you are good to go

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have defined Message Service in shared module only. Then I imported the shared module in UserModule and AppModule respectively. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098986/angular-4-shared-service-observable-behavior-subject . Maybe you should try moving that service out of the sharedmodule into your core module, so that it does not get defined twice

Answer (score 0):

Try without creating a new observable each time you call getMessage

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  private message = new Subject<any>();
  private messageEvent$ = this.message.asObservable();
  constructor() {}
  sendMessage(message) {
    this.message.next({ message: message });
  }
  clearMessage() {
    this.message.next();
  }
  getMessage() {
    return this.messageEvent$;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but sorry to say it did not work.
I have defined Message Service in shared module only. Then I imported the shared module in UserModule and AppModule respectively. Am I doing something wrong?